# Issue with filewriter and filereader

Tags: java, jtextfield, filereader, filewriter

I made a code which for change password in a local program i made. It is working almost very well, but i ran into a little issue. If i change the new password to "" (nothing), the file which are reading the password, doesnt works if i leave the field empty. It works fine if i type in a normal password like "hey". The password is stored in a txt file, so the problem is, that an empty JTextField doesnt equal an empty log file.. why? I need a fix of this. I would like it to work with the password (nothing), but some alternative fixes would be cool too.

This code checks password:

check is the string from readfile, and password is the string from my textfield.

```
if(event.getSource()==tf&&password.equals(check)){
  try{
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad C:\\Applications\\Infostore.txt");
  }catch(IOException ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
  }
  System.exit(1);
}else{
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Wrong password");
}
```

The password creater is an ordinary filewriter, which gets content from textfield, and write it in a txt file.

Comment: Better if you attach the codes for password saving and retrieving too..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test the value of your JTextField before saving the password.

```
if (textField.getText()==null) passwd = "";
```

Answer (score 1):

When the scanner reads your text file, if it reads an empty string at the end of the file it will assume the string is `null`. This is why it's probably always better to, when finished writing to a file, add a new line at the end of the file using [`BufferedWriter.newLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#newLine%28%29).

Otherwise, if you wish to stick with not adding a new line, or it does not work, try adding this to your password check:

```
if(check == null)
```

The reason why checking if the string is empty is, like I said before, possibly because the scanner thought it was the end of the file and returned the `check` string to be null.